# User created at the exact same time an order was placed. Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: customer, frontend

We have had an issue where a customer was able to create an account on one of our stores. We have external account creation disabled and use Formstack to generate login request emails. Each user has to be Created Manually.

This customer was able to create an account and checkout at the exact same time.

does anyone have any idea if there is a work around to making a login on a site with front end registration disabled?

Comment: so he created an account at checkout? I'm sure there is a setting for that in the backend to disable account creation at checkout if I understood your question...

Comment: yes @ClaudiuCreanga customer created an account at checkout time

Comment: It is not possible for customers to even add something to their shopping cart, you need to log in to see any pricing.

Comment: *"does anyone have any idea if there is a work around to making a login on a site with front end registration disabled?"* - I beg your pardon but that's a pretty broad way to ask. This might also be related why you don't get any answers so far but just comments. AFAIK 1.8.1.0 is outdated and can at least be patched. So this is the most obvious thing in my eyes here. It's most likely a flaw with the version + configuration you make use of.